# IK on eyeball does not move how I tell it to - Resolved

Tags: inverse-kinematics

So I have this IK restraint so that my eye follows a bone that I can position wherever I want the eye to look. However, I have come to find that when I try to move the handle, it is very sporadic. I have no idea why this happens but it is extremely frustrating as the eye generally ends up facing inwards. What might be the cause of this?

[image]

[image]

In the above image, you can see that I have the eye handle selected. You can see that the z value of this bone is -0.66056.
[image]

You can see in the above image that I have changed the z value to -0.65056. Notice that this also moved the legs slightly.

[image]

In the above image, I have returned the z value to -0.66056. The bone, however, does not return and moves further in the same direction as before. The legs move slightly too.

[image]

In the above image, you can see that switching the z value back and forth moves the bone around the constraint in a circle. Again, legs move.

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi again @moonboots I will share the file now. I honestly thought I was just being stupid and it would be obvious to someone. Thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific eye problem, you should not choose the eye bone as the parent of the eye handle bone, also give your eye bone a *Track To* constraint with the eye handle as bone target. You have other problems like you should apply your *Mirror* modifier, only the eye bone should influence the eye mesh, the control bones need to have their *Deform* option disabled, your IK handles should only have the root bone as parent, in Edit mode recalculate the bones roll with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, etc...

Comment: it seems that removing the parent and adding the Track To constraint fixed the issue. Everything else was good except the mirror. I do not understand why the common theme is to apply the mirror modifier. I have successfully rigged the model without applying it so far. and hey @moonboots , if you can answer the other question I posted yesterday about making my Spline IK follow the armature, it would be well appreciated!

Comment: ok I'll take a look if I have time  ;)